# Android remote Events gathering tool or event tracker

Tags: android, google-analytics, flurry-analytics

I'm looking for some... let's say 'event gathering platform' or 'event tracker + front end' for my android app.
I know there is a lot of tracking and analytics platforms (http://www.quora.com/Flurry-vs-Mixpanel-vs-Google-Mobile-Analytics-who-wins-Why) for mobiles, but still (after tried with Google Analytics, Flurry and Amplitiude) it is not what I exactly want.
These analytic platforms focuses rather on analysis from the business (who, where, how many times plus analysis etc.) than administrator's point of view. 
In my case there is always just one (maybe two or three in the future) same user (this is a non play store app).

What I really need is a service which gather events published by phone (id, labal, data, timestamp), store them and then present in some user friendly way.
So these are my requirements:

- able to gather (by some agent) and store events with its data and time-stamps
- allows to display the gathered events by web browser (on timeline) with some filters and search options (some front-end)
- allows to export data (f.e to csv file or any other kind of format)
- has to be for free or a few $ per month
- nice if it works in real time

I'm looking forward to any suggestions.

Maybe this help to understand what I'm looking for:

http://trackingsmartphone.com/ it is almost what I would like to have, but the remote control over device is not obligatory for me and I'm looking for something what works not pro phone by pro particular app (so I can define events I would like to gather).

So basically I need something between Flurry and trackingsmartphone.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Would something like Piwik (http://piwik.org/) fit the bill? They have an Android SDK on Github as well: https://github.com/piwik/piwik-sdk-android

Comment: Looks interesting. Has even some plugins ability. Thx, this is a one of the directions I'm going to investigate.